# BitmapData vs Image<,>.Data when accessing to pixel value - performance

Tags: c#, image, performance, image-processing, emgucv

I'm working on an tool for image processing (C#, using a EmguCV)
I need to get best performance on single operations on pixels.

I have read a lot of threads about `LockBit()` and copying a values from pointer to array of byte as a BEST method (when performance is priority) to get/set pixel value.

I found some implementations like this:
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/240428/Work-with-bitmap-faster-with-Csharp

And I have compared it to much simpler method:

```
Image<Bgr, byte> image = new Image<Bgr, byte>(Bitmap);
byte[,,] data = image.Data;

//And then get r channel like:
byte rChannel = data[y,x,0];

//And set r channel like:
data[y,x,0] = color.R;
```

So, I have used a implementation from link above but i cut out a creating `Color` like `Color.FromArgb(r, g, b);` and assume that image depth = 24, just to optimilize performance (I'm returning a 1D array of byte as a color)

My results (Image 2048x2048 - 4194304 operations of comparing color of pixel with `Color.White` - done 3 times):

```
Via `LockBit()` and pointer method:
00:00:00.7971876
00:00:00.7569262
00:00:00.7693977

Via `Image<,>.Data` method:
00:00:00.7957318
00:00:00.8136698
00:00:00.8010817
```

I dont see any significant performance difference between a unsafe `LockBits()` and pointer method and pretty clear and easy `Image<,>.Data` one.

Can someone explain me why the `LockBits()/Pointer` method is called a super fast? Maybe I'm missing something (as I said - i have used a implementation from link above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you asking why using `LockBits()` is "called a super fast"? It's not entirely clear to me what "first one" refers to here.

That said, the important question is whether your code needs to transition to the graphics driver (which handles bitmap operations) or not. The transition is very expensive, and happens every time you call a method like `GetPixel()` or `SetPixel()`.

Hence APIs like the `LockBits()` method. In such approaches, you copy all of the data in a single transition to the graphics driver, into memory your program has direct access to. Then you operate on that memory directly. Then you copy it back to the bitmap (if necessary) in another single transition.

As compared to using `GetPixel()` and `SetPixel()`, something like `LockBits()` *is* extremely fast. But `LockBits()` is not the only way to achieve that kind of performance. *Any* API that avoids the transition to and from the graphics driver will be "super fast". Since EmguCV is similar to using `LockBits()`, in that it doesn't involve numerous transitions between your code and the graphics driver, it will be similarly fast.

Look at it this way: using `GetPixel()` and `SetPixel()` is sort of like riding a bike, while using `LockBits()` and EmguCV are more like driving a race car. The latter two aren't identical; one race car and/or its driver will be slightly slower or faster than another. But both are *way* faster than human-powered transportation.

Comment: I was rather asking "Is there should be any significant difference between using those 2 methods? Maybe I'm missing something what will make a difference" But last 2 paragraphs perfect clear it to me :) Thank you